# Magento media url - get rid of 403 Forbidden

Tags: apache, magento, magento-1.4

on my Magento site (not the real url ;) ), I have http://magento.local.com/media/ returning as a 403 Forbidden.

This seems to be standard for all Magento installs, but I want to change this, and not have a 403 returned for requests to /media/.

How can I do this?

EDIT: (adding further information and reason for it)

I want /media/ to not be a 403, so that I can redirect requests to /media/ to /media/index.html.

I thought this redirect would be easy once the 403 was resolved, but unfortunately it is not. e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^$ /index.html [L,NC,R=301]
```

does not redirect /media/ at all, and the usual "Index of /" is displayed.

SOLUTION: add DirectoryIndex to the htaccess file

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put `.htaccess` to your `media/` dir with following contents:

```
Options All +Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

Comment: Thanks, that does stop the 403 alright, and I know this is basic, but what I want is to display an index file for request to that url. E.g. redirect /media/ to /media/index.html. So now it displays the apache "index of /" page, and a htaccess redirect it not working. I tried RewriteRule ^$ /index.html [L,NC,R=301]
 but it does not redirect.

Comment: see my edit. make sure you have index.html file in media dir.

Answer (score 0):

Something to pay attention to.

The standard Magento .htaccess for the media directory is as follows:

```
Options All -Indexes
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag engine 0
</IfModule>

# AddHandler cgi-script .php .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi
Options -ExecCGI
```

Due to the relaxed permissions Magento expects on this directory tree, they wish to prevent execution and interpretation of php and other scripts that could be maliciously uploaded into the directory tree and then executed remotely. As long as this function is preserved, you will be ok on modifications you make.