# Magento media url not working

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to clear that I have already went through this post:

[Magento media url - get rid of 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284767/magento-media-url-get-rid-of-403-forbidden)

but I am not still able to get image url from media library. I have tried all these URLs:

> localhost/magento/media/customer/pic1.jpg (access forbidden error)
>   localhost/magento/media/index.html/customer/pic1.jpg (object not found error but image is present)
>   localhost/magento/media/index.html (working but of no use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct link is localhost/magento/media/customer/pic1.jpg.
Try to set correct files ownership and permissions.
For apache2 server default configuration:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/magento
find /var/www/html/magento/media/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
find /var/www/html/magento/media/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
```

Comment: sorry didnot work after it owner become www-data but in my downloads file it is 'Me' as owner

Comment: Do you use apache with www-data user? Could you provide your whole magento folder path?

Answer (score 0):

I have to make a index.html and .htaccess file same as media folder(as in my referenced link) and to place in media/customer too. it has been fixed now and working with url : localhost/magento/media/customer/pic1.jpg.